# Densly Packed c++ container

Tags: c++, containers, mpi

I write code that deals heavily with numbers. For a project I need to pass big "matrices" via MPI between different processes. These matrices are just rectangular number containers I only need to do trivial operations on them. As far as I know to pass such objects in MPI the procedure is to pass a pointer to the first element of the matrix and its size, therefore the matrix must be densely packed, exactly as a plain C array would be:`double matrix[n][m]`, where all the elements are contiguous and immediately after the first row the second row starts. The C++ solution would be to use `std::array<std::array<double,m>,n>` (n and m are known at compile time) however I have too many data and I need to allocate memory on the heap; I do not think it is possible to allocate `std::array` on the heap. A similar solution using `std::vector` would not work since they are not densely packed.
Is there a modern C++ solution to the problem? Do I have to use the old C arrays or do I need to write a wrapper class around them? What about using `std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>` is it guaranteed to be densely packed?

Comment: Why _not_ use a C-style array?  Do you need any of the C++ features?  Special iterators?  Resizing of arrays?  If not, the easiest and most efficient thing is a plain old array.

Comment: Mostly safety, like using the possibility of using .at(). And a bit because of syntactic sugar like the possibility of not defining an operator /= since std::valarray has it defined by itself. I need to perform element wise mathematical operation, I do not need to perform "linear algebra" operations.

Comment: "std::vector would not work since they are not densely packed" what exactly do you mean? `std::vector` and `std::array` store their data in a c-array

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<double>> is not densely packed. Each row is stored in a contiguous way, but after one row there is the buffer to allow it to grow.

Comment: ok then I understood you correctly ;)

Comment: btw its not the case there is a buffer after each row, but rather the rows can be scattered around in memory. When a vector grows it may need to reallocate and move its elements to different memory

Comment: a C++ friendly option is to use `boost::multi_array` as described in an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>>
```

is not the best container when it comes to memory locality. The big plus of `std::vector` is that it used contiguous memory, but a vector of vectors looses that feature. You could consider to use a

```
std::vector<std::array<T>>
```

which is probably the most cache-friendly nested 2D array. Alternatively consider

```
std::vector<T>
```

with `width * height` elements. 2D access can be emulated by tranforming the index ( `(i,j) -> i`) and `std::vector<T>::data()` gets you a pointer to the underlying c-array that has nothing but your elements in contiguous memory.